# TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not _io.BytesIO

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, io, odoo-8, odoo-11

haii everyone...

i have one module in odoo8 version its contain Import the products and quantity in inventory adjustment in that read the file code is there

```
import cStringIO


data = base64.b64decode(self.data)

self.data contain the file path..

file_input = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
```

it is working fine in odoo8.

I want to implement this module in odoo11

in odoo python version is changes that' way it does not know about the cStringIO. it knows only StringIO

```
from io import StringIO

import io

data = base64.b64decode(self.data)

file_input = io.StringIO(data)

raise error 

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

i changes the code above lines
but it does not take the data. because it is return bytes form, here it want string

then next i had use

```
file_input = io.BytesIO(data) -->this

raise the error

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

please any one help me to rectify this ...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your last error makes no sense. The error implies you tried to pass an `io.BytesIO` to `io.StringIO`. Post a true [MCVE]; what you've provided isn't reproducible.

Comment: data = base64.b64decode(self.data)
file_input = cStringIO.StringIO(data) file_input.seek(0)

Comment: but it is not working in odoo11. for odoo11 working what i want to change.                 the problem is total this line                    
        file_input = cStringIO.StringIO(data)

Comment: Yes, you said that. But then you claimed `io.BytesIO(data)` has the same error, and it shouldn't. You need to clarify the problem (edit the question, to fix it, don't post comments, especially with code, which can't be formatted in comments).

Comment: ok i have edit the question. then please tell me u have any idea about how to change decode csv file from byte to string... i have stuck this line

Comment: in python3 cstringIO and stringIO is remove. instead of using io.stringIO, when i use this its raise error TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes........ then i change io.stringIO to io.BytesIO it is not read the file. raise the exception Not a valid file!. please tell what to do

Answer (score -1):

replace this:

```
data = base64.b64decode(self.data)
```

to:

```
data = base64.b64decode(self.data).decode('utf-8')
```